# Getting values from JSON using appscript

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I'm creating two-dimentional array with google appscript using chrome devices users with the JSON response from a directory. I've been able to get values. However, when I try to get recentUsers represented as:

```
    {
    "kind": "directory#chromeosdevices",
    "chromeosdevices": [
     {
       "kind": "directory#chromeosdevice",
       "etag": "1234567890"
       "deviceId": "def456",
       "serialNumber": "234567",
       "status": "ACTIVE",
       "lastSync": "2013-03-05T17:30:04.325Z",
       "supportEndDate": "2014-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
       "annotatedUser": "help desk",
       "annotatedLocation": "Mountain View help desk Chromebook",
       "annotatedAssetId": "1234567890",
       "notes": "Loaned from support",
       "orderNumber": "1234",
       "willAutoRenew": true,
       "osVersion": "Browser Version 18.0",
       "platformVersion": "Platform Version 1415.2.0",
       "firmwareVersion": "Firmware Version 1.2.3.4",
       "bootMode": "validated",
       "lastEnrollmentTime": "2012-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
       "orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",
       "recentUsers": [
         {
           "type": "USER_TYPE_MANAGED",
           "email": "user@customer.com" //I'm trying to get the most recent user's email 
         }
       ],
       "activeTimeRanges": [
         {
           "date": "2012-04-05",
           "activeTime": "3600000"
         }
       ],
     }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "abcdefghijkl123"
}
```

I get an array but I can't get the value. I'm trying to get the most recent user's email. Anyone have experience with appscript? I've tried recentUsers[0].email and recentUser[0]['email']. This is the code I have to far: //I commented where I'm trying to push a value
enter code here

```
var chromeArgs = {   
  maxResults: 200,
  orderBy: 'annotatedUser',
  projection: "FULL"
 
};


var getChromes = (AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list('XXXXXXXXX', chromeArgs));

var chromes = getChromes.chromeosdevices;
   if (chromes && chromes.length > 0) {
 Logger.log('Devices:');
 //2d array
 var wholeValues = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < chromes.length; i++){  
//create a 1D array first with pushing 0,1,2 elements with a for loop
   var value = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
     var chrms = chromes[i];
     var recentUser = chrms.recentUsers;
     value.push(recentUser[0].email); // Here is where I need help 
}
    //pushing the value array with [0,1,2] to thw wholeValues array. 
    wholeValues.push(value);
  } // the outer for loop runs five times , so five the 0,1,2 with be pushed in to thewholevalues array by creating wholeValues[0][0],wholeValues[0][1]...till..wholeValues[4][2]

  Logger.log(wholeValues); '''
```

Comment: 1. What happens if you just do `AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list('my_customer').chromeosdevices[0].recentUsers[0].email`? 2. What is the content of the array which value you cannot get? 3. What is the content of `chromeArgs`?

Comment: 1. It gives me the same email over and over. 
2. I updated the json, i cant get the email of recentUsers
3. I updated the code to show chromeArgs 
@ziganotschka thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are very close, the only thing you need to change is to replace the static `recentUsers[0]` with dynamic `recentUsers[j]` within the loop

Sample:

```js
function getChromes(){
  var chromeArgs = {   
    maxResults: 200,
    orderBy: 'annotatedUser',
    projection: "FULL"  
  };   
  var getChromes = (AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list('XXXXXXXXX', chromeArgs));  
  var chromes = getChromes.chromeosdevices;
  if (chromes && chromes.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Devices:');
    var wholeValues = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i < chromes.length; i++){  
      var chrms = chromes[i];
      var recentUser = chrms.recentUsers;
      var value = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < recentUser.length; j++) {
        Logger.log(recentUser[j].email);
        value.push(recentUser[j].email); 
      } 
      wholeValues.push(value);
    }     
    Logger.log(wholeValues); 
  }
}
```

Note that you need to specify the iteration limit of the inner loop dynamically `j < recentUser.length;` instead of `j < 1` to account for different quantity of recent users for each chrome device.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help @ziganotschka, but I get 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: When I push chrms.recentUsers
I get in return: 
 [{email=example@email.com, type=USER_TYPE_MANAGED}]

Comment: value.push(recentUser[j].email); 
gives me: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What does `Logger.log(recentUser[j])` Return you?

Comment: it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for that line

Comment: Oh, I see now - there is an issue with your second loop: it should be `for (var j = 0; j < recentUser.length; j++) {` to account for the fact that there might be only 1 or 0 recent users. Otherwise, if you loop through `recentUser[1]` and there is no `recentUser[1]` - this will give you the type error.

Comment: you're right, when there is recentUser[0], I get an undefined. So I added the following try to the second for loop to catch an error and it works like a charm
         try { // Try to get the recentUsers if there is an error push the error to the array
               recentU = chrms.recentUsers[0].email;
          } catch (e) {
               recentU = 'none'
          }